# Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'typeof import'

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I upgraded react-native-reanimated from version 2 to version 3.6.2
but in the Animated.Value code an error occurs:

```
Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/macbook/Desktop/.../.../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/lib/typescript/Animated" )'
```

This is the code I am using:
`const fall = new Animated.Value(1);`